# AWS CodeBuild Visual Studio 2019 build tools

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

Is there a way to install `Visual Studio 2019 build tools` on CodeBuild that is using the `aws/codebuild/windows-base:2019-1.0` image?

I receive the following error when running the `choco install visualstudio2019buildtools -Y` command:

```
ERROR: Running ["C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\visualstudio2019buildtools\16.11.13.0\vs_BuildTools.exe" update --wait --quiet --norestart --installPath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"] was not successful. Exit code was '1'. See log for possible error messages.
The install of visualstudio2019buildtools was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2019buildtools\tools\ChocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.

Chocolatey installed 2/3 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - visualstudio2019buildtools (exited 1) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2019buildtools\tools\ChocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.

[Container] 2022/05/06 07:57:35 Command did not exit successfully choco install visualstudio2019buildtools -Y --force -limit-output exit status 1
[Container] 2022/05/06 07:57:35 Phase complete: INSTALL State: FAILED
[Container] 2022/05/06 07:57:35 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: choco install visualstudio2019buildtools -Y --force -limit-output. Reason: exit status 1
```

Comment: Try running `set-executionpolicy remotesigned` before running `choco install...` - does that work? It seems that it's trying to run a PowerShell script and I know that by default, the Windows PowerShell restricted execution policy won't let you. If that doesn't work, try grabbing and adding the output of `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log` after it fails to your question please.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem when I issued wrong installation parameters with choco command and it seems like the installer was downloaded but failed to be installed.

Restarting windows server did not help since installation was done half way and I could not uninstall it. Issuing this command did not help either - set-executionpolicy remotesigned. Neither did using "--force" helped

I had to redeploy the windows server/ get a new instance deployed with the correct choco command and everything work well